# How to calculate miss-rate and miss types of a matriz stored in memory?

Tags: caching, computer-science, virtual-memory

I been trying to do this exercise ((d), (e), (f), and (g) points) but I can't figure out how to do them.

Given a square matrix A of NxN integers, where N = 32 and the integers occupy 4 bytes. The first index represents rows, the second columns and both are numbered from 0 to N-1. The matrix is ​​stored in memory following a row-major order, that is, the element A[i][j] is found at memory location: base_address_of_A + (i * N + j) * element_size.

a) Assuming that the base address of array A is 0410H, what is the base address of the second row? what is the address of the component A[N-1][N-1] of the matrix?
Assuming you have 16-bit physical memory addresses and a 512-byte physical cache for data, implemented with direct mapping and 32-byte lines.

b) Indicate how the physical address is divided to access the cache and how many bits each part has.

c) Indicate how many blocks the matrix is ​​divided into, what is the base address of each block (at least for the first 4 rows) and what is the cache index associated with each one.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ej0B.png)

Assuming that starting with each scan in the data cache there is nothing useful and that you operate on the indices
involved in the traversal does not imply memory accesses because they are stored in registers.

d) For each tour, how many failures occurred due to data access? what was the failure rate?
e) Of the total number of failures, what is the percentage of compulsive failures?
f) Which of the two routes is more recommended? Justify.
g) What would have happened if the matrix was stored in memory following a column-major order, that is That is, if the element A[i][j] were found at memory location base_address_of_A + (j * N + i) * item_size?

I guessed for a,b and c:

a) second-row adress: 0490h and the last-element adress is 140C

b) tag = 5 bits, offset = 4 bits, and index = 5 bits.

c) is divided into 128 block of 8 elements each.

the following exercises are the ones I cannot guess.

I think that the path 1 is the slower option, but i couldn't figure out HOW to calculate the misses